# Generating JWK with a private key while using jose4j to generate JWS

Tags: java, jwt, jwk, jwe, jose4j

I am trying to generate a JWK using my private key while using jose4j library to generate a JWE with the earlier mentioned JWK. But the key generated doesn't seem to be correct, also, it doesn't have all the fields (only n, e and kty get generated , expected fields are kty, n, e, d, p, q, dp, dq, qi). Any suggestions?

I am using the following code :

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(privateKeyString);
    PrivateKey privateKey =
        KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decoded));
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPrivateKeySpec privKeySpec = kf.getKeySpec(privateKey, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);
    RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec =
        new RSAPublicKeySpec(privKeySpec.getModulus(), privKeySpec.getPrivateExponent());
    RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
    RsaJsonWebKey jwkp = (RsaJsonWebKey) PublicJsonWebKey.Factory.newPublicJwk(pubKey);
    jwkp.setPrivateKey(privateKey);
    jwkp.toJson(JsonWebKey.OutputControlLevel.PUBLIC_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 1):

`JsonWebKey.OutputControlLevel.INCLUDE_PRIVATE` needs to be explicitly used in the `toJson(...)` call for the private key field(s) to be included. That's d specifically. The others - p, q, dp, dq, qi - will be there if it's a `RSAPrivateCrtKey`